# On using subtle with observation

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I am familiar with using the word subtle with differences (`subtle differences`), but not sure how does it sound if used with observation (subtle observation). I want to say important observation that not anyone can see.

Comment: For me it is not really correct (the observation itself is not subtle) but I am sure you would be understood, and you will probably find that this phrase has been used before.

Comment: I would instead use *covert* or *discreet* observation.